# Разница между Rigidbody и Character Controller?

Tags: unity3d

**Разница между Rigidbody (RB) и Character Controller? (CC)**

Я никак не могу понять, в некоторых уроках мне предлагают использовать как **контроллер движения** только **RB** а в некоторых только **CC**, и так же моменты где используют и **CC** и **RB** но при этом нет проблем, в моем же случае мой обьект с **RB** и **CC** проваливается не учитывая капсульный коллайдер от **CC**, тогда что и где будет правильным и корректным решением?

**Controller** нужен для перемещения персонажей, но какой и как его и с чем его использовать?

Спасибо.

Comment: RigidBody - это объект физического движка, CharacterController - это скрипт, управляющий объектом. Сравнивать эти понятия все равно что сравнивать теплое с мягким.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Компонент CharacterController есть только в 3D проекте, то есть если работать с 2D, то этого компонента не существует. Поэтому в 2D проекте используют RigidBody2D для задания перемещения героя, и почти всегда скрипт с движением героя называют как "Character Controller"